# build a custom simple parser in JavaScript for further processing

Tags: javascript, parsing, recursion

For a project of mine I have to analyze a bunch of simple html formatted strings and further process them.

Let's say I have a string like:

```
Hey <font face="Times New Roman" size="14">this text look <i>cool<i> and <b>fancy <i>very fancy<i></b> however </font> I'm ok <u>with</u> it.
```

What I would like to obtain with my recursive function is an array with various objects as child structured as follows:

```
var myArr = myParse(myString);

myArr[0] = {
    "text": "Hey",
}
myArr[0] = {
    "text": "this text look ",
    "face": "Times New Roman",
    "size": 14
}
myArr[1] = {
    "text": "cool",
    "face": "Times New Roman",
    "size": 14,
    "italic": true
}
myArr[2] = {
    "text": " and ",
    "face": "Times New Roman",
    "size": 14
}
myArr[3] = {
    "text": "fancy ",
    "face": "Times New Roman",
    "size": 14,
    "bold": true
}
myArr[4] = {
    "text": "fancy ",
    "face": "Times New Roman",
    "size": 14,
    "bold": true
}
myArr[5] = {
    "text": "very fancy",
    "face": "Times New Roman",
    "size": 14,
    "italic": true,
    "bold": true
}
myArr[6] = {
    "text": " however ",
    "face": "Times New Roman",
    "size": 14
}
myArr[6] = {
    "text": " I'm ok "
}
myArr[7] = {
    "text": "with",
    "underline": true
}
myArr[8] = {
    "text": " it."
}
```

I tried to structure it as recursive function but I'm unsure how to proceed to make it completely functional..

```
function myParse(str, arr) {

    if(!arr) arr = [];

    var regex = /<font(.+?)>(.+?)<\/font>|<i>(.+?)<\/i>|<b>(.+?)<\/b>|<u>(.+?)<\/u>/g;
    var match = regex.exec(str);
    while (match != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < match.length; i++) {

            // this way i can identify with matches:
            // match[1] - font specifics
            // match[2] - font tag content
            // match[3] - italic tag content
            // match[4] - bold tag content
            // match[5] - underline tag content

            var temp_object = {};

            var temp_object.text = matched_text;
            // process here a second regex to obtain font name and size.. like:
            var regex = /face="(.+?)"|size="(.+?)"/g;
            ...
            var temp_object.italic = match[3] ? true : false;
            var temp_object.bold = match[4] ? true : false;
            var temp_object.underline = match[5] ? true : false;

            // at some point i'm pretty sure that i have to..
            // put a marker let's say a
            var marker = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000).toString();
            str.replace(matched_text, marker)

            // then recurse the parse(str, arr)  
        }
        match = regex.exec(str);
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't parse HTML with a RegEx. Just don't do it  -- HTML is not a regular language, it is a context free grammar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: I agree with @mrunion.  You'll have better luck if you break the problem down into two steps: 1. build a full representation of the HTML tree and 2. extract the text information you want from the tree structure into a flat list.  Both steps are sufficiently complex alone that trying to intermingle the logic is bound to lead to confusion.

Plus, you can (probably?) find an html parser that will do step one for you and save yourself from the trickiest part of the problem.

Comment: @JoshDoebbert I found this: https://johnresig.com/files/htmlparser.js however is not usable for me. My script will not run in a browser environment so document.body and all other browser related objects are undefined.

Comment: A quick search brought me to https://github.com/fb55/htmlparser2 but please don't take this comment as an endorsement. SO specifically excludes questions asking for tool recommendations, although I think "use an available tool" is acceptable advice. You could  also try using a headless browser.